# In the XCode IDE how can you scroll the window with the keyboard?

Tags: xcode4, keyboard, scroll

This is for XCode 4, while one is working on a project in the IDE. I'd like the equivalent of `Ctr+Up Arrow`/`Ctr+Down Arrow` in Eclipse, so I can scroll the current window without moving the cursor from the keyboard.

Couldn't find it in Google, since all my searches return results for scrolling things on the iPhone.

Comment: For those of us that don't develop in Eclipse, what EXACTLY does Ctrl-Up do in Eclipse?

Comment: @MDT it scrolls the current window one line at a time without moving the cursor. It is the keyboard equivalent of turning the mouse scroll wheel.

Comment: @MDT - also, see subject line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Peter I did see the subject line, I was just hoping you could clarify that for me, and there are several configurations for scrolling with the keyboard in Xcode (screenshot below). Beyond this I don't think theres anything you can do. Hope this helps!

EDIT: If this is what you're looking for, good news! You'll be able to configure them to the shortcuts you already know in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does look like what I am looking for. I can only get to a Mac on Monday to verify.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mighty mouse - you can configure a Single Touch Top to scroll just like the iphone tap on uitableview. You can download BetterTouchTool here http://blog.boastr.net/

[image]